# undefined class config and path for {{Config::get('app.url')}}

Tags: php, laravel

May I know what for the code below to add because "undefined class config" error and what does the path for {{Config::get('app.url')}} means?

Here is the view file name as (master.blade.php)

```
<link type="text/css" href="{{Config::get('app.url')}}/theme/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

1. The `Config` class is used to access settings defined in your application's `config/` folder. The path you give it tells it which file to look into and which properties inside that file it should return. The path 'app.url' tells it get the config from `config/app.php` and retrieve the `url` property. (NOTE: There's more to it than that. Laravel loads these files on application boot into a repository and then looks at that repo when you call for a setting. That is why you should not try to call a config file from inside another config file. https://blog.maqe.com/dont-use-laravel-s-config-inside-config-files-40e2c8207225)
2. You're getting an error because the view doesn't recognize the class `Config` the way you're calling it. You can either put a backslash at the beginning like `\Config::get(...)` or use the `config()` helper to prevent the error: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-config
3. However, since you're using this to import a style sheet, you can actually use the `asset()` helper function instead. The `asset()` helper function creates a URL to a file inside your `public` folder: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-asset

`<link type="text/css" href="{{ asset('theme/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Comment: thanks for the explanation. So If I using the asset() helper function, does it mean the css file I need to put under the public folder? which mean the path should be looks like this "public/theme/css/bootstrap.css" ?

Comment: The css file should be inside the `public/theme/css` folder. You don't need to add '/public' to the url to access it, since the url is already pointing to the `public` folder inside your laravel application.